# Example of knowledge representation as a surrogate for something in the world

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, knowledge-representation

I've been trying to learn about knowledge representations.

According to a [canonical definition](http://cse3521.artifice.cc/knowledge-representation.html), a knowledge representation is:

> - a surrogate for real-world entities
> - an ontological commitment about what kinds of entities are relevant

The notion of surrogate is nicely described in the same source:

> For any entity (surrogate) in the knowledge representation, we have to
>   be sure we have a good argument for:
>
> - "correspondence": what does this entity in the KR represent in reality?
> - "fidelity": how well does it match what it is supposed to represent?

Can someone help me think of a useful heuristic to understand what is meant by a surrogate here?  The best example I can think of is a map (which has both correspondence and fidelity )

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge representation is a model of a certain domain of the real world.

These models are composed from objecttypes (entity, surrogate) and the relations between objecttypes.

Such models are named "ontologies" and can be formalized as "Entity-relationship-models".

Ontologies are used e.g., in business-administration to model a certain business domain. In sales we have entities like *customer*, *order*, *product* and relationsships between the entities *customer* and *order* like *customer places an order*, and between *order* and *product* like *an order comprises several products*. These ontologies are the prerequisites for database design.

Comment: Ok, thanks- clear. but this describes more about the utility of ontology and Leeds about what a surrogate is. what criteria are used in determining what can be a surrogate?

Comment: @Teusz I enclose a link to a paper of one of the founders of entity-relationship modeling http://bit.csc.lsu.edu/~chen/pdf/Chen_Pioneers.pdf  An entitytype covers instances with the same attributes, e.g. the entitytype customer covers instances with a name, an address, a solvency etc. Which entitytypes one chooses depends on the aim of the intended model. Only the formal structure of the model is prescribed - not its content.

Comment: But is an entity type the same thing as a surrogate?

Comment: @Teusz I have never heard the term *surrogate* in the context of data modeling. Your quote introduced the term as a synonym for entity.